# Happstack ServerPart missing MonadIO instance?

Tags: haskell, happstack

The following code:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class

import Happstack.Server

test :: ServerPart String
test = liftIO (putStrLn "Test") >> ok "Test"

main = simpleHTTP nullConf test
```

is failing to compile with the message:

```
No instance for (MonadIO (ServerPartT IO))
  arising from a use of `liftIO'
Possible fix:
  add an instance declaration for (MonadIO (ServerPartT IO))
In the first argument of `(>>)', namely `liftIO (putStrLn "Test")'
In the expression: liftIO (putStrLn "Test") >> ok "Test"
In an equation for `test':
    test = liftIO (putStrLn "Test") >> ok "Test"
```

There appears to be a MonadIO instance here:

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/happstack-server-7.4.0/docs/Happstack-Server-Monads.html#t:ServerPartT

but adding a `Happstack.Server.Monads` import didn't change anything so I was hoping someone might be able to indicate what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: On a hunch, are `happstack-server` and your program using the same version of `transformers`?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I had that thought as well but I'm not sure how to check definitively? It looks like I have both 0.3.0.0 (from the Haskell Platform) and 0.4.2.0 (from Cabal) in ghc-pkg list but I don't know how to tell which is being used for what?

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen I tried unregistering each version, and it looks like happstack is dependent on 0.3 and I would presume my program would try to use 0.4.2 since it's newer? Would you have any advice regarding resolving the issue?

Comment: @ZJM You can use cabal sandbox, it ensures package versions consistency. BTW there is a feature request to improve the error: https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9611

Comment: @Yuras Using a sandbox resolved it. Unfortunately it seems like I'll need to change my development workflow to make use of it, but I think long term it's for the best anyway.